# jQuery Mobile button js control

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-events

I have a button that is not triggering event in jQuery mobile. It was working but I had to remove the css. It was screwing up my all my ul lists. Any help would greatly appreciated

Here is the code for the button at the bottom of the form :

```
      <div class="next">                                
                <a class="btnNext">Next &gt;&gt;</a>

            </div>
```

Which is supposed to do this on a separate js file:

```
init: function(){
        $('.btnNext').onclick(function(){
            if ($('input[type=radio]:checked:visible').length == 0) {

                return false;
            }
            $(this).parents('.questionContainer').fadeOut(500, function(){
```

Here is the css I removed:

```
a  {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 10px;
    background: #FFF;
    cursor: pointer;
 }
a:hover {
background: none;
}
```

Comment: In jQuery isn't it just "click", not "onclick"?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    //You need use $('.btnNext').live('click',function(){ or $('.btnNext').click(function(){
    $('.btnNext').live('click',function(){
        if ($('input[type=radio]:checked:visible').length == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        //your other code
   });
```